# getChildHtml() not working for a product landingpage block

Tags: magento-1.8, product, php, layout

I'm working on a landingpage for a single product. 
Herefore I created a CMS Page with the following content:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_view" product_id="1896" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml"}}
```

The problem is that inside the `view.phtml` `getChildHtml` is not working. Any suggestions how to solve it?

The Layout looks like this:

```
 <catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Any)</label>
    <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/3columns.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs">
            <script>varien/product.js</script>
        </action>
        <action method="addJs">
            <script>varien/configurable.js</script>
        </action>

        <action method="addItem">
            <type>js_css</type>
            <name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name>
            <params/>
            <!--<if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>-->
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>js</type>
            <name>calendar/calendar.js</name>
            <!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>-->
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>js</type>
            <name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name>
            <!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>-->
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related"
               template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">

            <!--
            <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/summary.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>short</type><template>review/helper/summary_short.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>...</type><template>...</template></action>
            -->
            <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media"
                   template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" translate="label">
                <label>Alert Urls</label>
            </block>

            <action method="setTierPriceTemplate">
                <template>catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml</template>
            </action>

            <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products"
                   template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
                <action method="setColumnCount">
                    <columns>4</columns>
                </action>
                <action method="setItemLimit">
                    <type>upsell</type>
                    <limit>4</limit>
                </action>
            </block>

            <block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional"
                   as="product_additional_data"/>
            <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional"
                   template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup">
                    <group>detailed_info</group>
                </action>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description"
                   template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup">
                    <group>detailed_info</group>
                </action>
            </block>

            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addto" as="addto"
                   template="catalog/product/view/addto.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart"
                   template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" translate="label">
                <label>Product View Extra Hint</label>
            </block>

            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper"
                   template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml" translate="label">
                <label>Info Column Options Wrapper</label>
                <block type="core/template" name="options_js" template="catalog/product/view/options/js.phtml"/>
                <block type="catalog/product_view_options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options"
                       template="catalog/product/view/options.phtml">
                    <action method="addOptionRenderer">
                        <type>text</type>
                        <block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block>
                        <template>catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</template>
                    </action>
                    <action method="addOptionRenderer">
                        <type>file</type>
                        <block>catalog/product_view_options_type_file</block>
                        <template>catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml</template>
                    </action>
                    <action method="addOptionRenderer">
                        <type>select</type>
                        <block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block>
                        <template>catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml</template>
                    </action>
                    <action method="addOptionRenderer">
                        <type>date</type>
                        <block>catalog/product_view_options_type_date</block>
                        <template>catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml</template>
                    </action>
                </block>
                <block type="core/html_calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar"
                       template="page/js/calendar.phtml"/>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom"
                   as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml"
                   translate="label">
                <label>Bottom Block Options Wrapper</label>
                <action method="insert">
                    <block>product.tierprices</block>
                </action>
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.clone_prices" as="prices"
                       template="catalog/product/view/price_clone.phtml"/>
                <action method="append">
                    <block>product.info.addtocart</block>
                </action>
                <action method="append">
                    <block>product.info.addto</block>
                </action>
            </block>

            <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container1" as="container1">
                <action method="setDataByKey">
                    <key>alias_in_layout</key>
                    <value>container1</value>
                </action>
                <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry">
                    <key>options_container</key>
                    <key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry>
                </action>
                <action method="append">
                    <block>product.info.options.wrapper</block>
                </action>
                <action method="append">
                    <block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block>
                </action>
            </block>
            <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
                <action method="setDataByKey">
                    <key>alias_in_layout</key>
                    <value>container2</value>
                </action>
                <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry">
                    <key>options_container</key>
                    <key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry>
                </action>
                <action method="append">
                    <block>product.info.options.wrapper</block>
                </action>
                <action method="append">
                    <block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block>
                </action>
            </block>
            <action method="unsetCallChild">
                <child>container1</child>
                <call>ifEquals</call>
                <if>0</if>
                <key>alias_in_layout</key>
                <key>options_container</key>
            </action>
            <action method="unsetCallChild">
                <child>container2</child>
                <call>ifEquals</call>
                <if>0</if>
                <key>alias_in_layout</key>
                <key>options_container</key>
            </action>
        </block>

    </reference>
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-"
               template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

The view.phtml:

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php echo get_class($this); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
<div class="product-view">
  <div class="product-essential">
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post"
          id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if ($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
      <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
      <div class="no-display">
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value=""/>
      </div>

      <div class="product-shop">
        <div class="product-name">
          <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
        </div>

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>

        <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()): ?>
          <div class="add-to-box">
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
              <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
              <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl = $this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
              <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </div>
          <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
        <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
          <div class="add-to-box">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
          </div>
        <?php endif; ?>



        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other'); ?>


      </div>
      <div class="product-img-box">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
      </div>

      <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //<![CDATA[
      var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
      productAddToCartForm.submit = function (button, url) {
        if (this.validator.validate()) {
          var form = this.form;
          var oldUrl = form.action;

          if (url) {
            form.action = url;
          }
          var e = null;
          try {
            this.form.submit();
          } catch (e) {
          }
          this.form.action = oldUrl;
          if (e) {
            throw e;
          }

          if (button && button != 'undefined') {
            button.disabled = true;
          }
        }
      }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

      productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function (button, url) {
        if (this.validator) {
          var nv = Validation.methods;
          delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
          delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
          delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
          // Remove custom datetime validators
          for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
            if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
              delete Validation.methods[methodName];
            }
          }

          if (this.validator.validate()) {
            if (url) {
              this.form.action = url;
            }
            this.form.submit();
          }
          Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
        }
      }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
      //]]>
    </script>

    <div class="product-collateral">
      <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()): ?>
        <div class="short-description box-collateral open">
          <h2><?php echo $this->__('Quick Overview') ?><i class="icon-arrow"></i></h2>

          <div
            class="std"><?php echo strip_tags($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description')) ?></div>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php foreach ($this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml') as $alias => $html): ?>
        <div class="box-collateral <?php echo "box-{$alias}" ?> open">
          <?php if ($title = $this->getChildData($alias, 'title')): ?>
            <h2><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?><i class="icon-arrow"></i></h2>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <?php echo $html; ?>
        </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
      <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>


    </div>

  </div>


</div>
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".paypal-logo").css({"display": "none"});
  });</script>

<?php
if ($_product) {
  $categories = $_product->getCategoryCollection()
    ->setPageSize(1)
    ->setPage(1, 1)
    ->addFieldToFilter('level', "5")
    //->addFieldToFilter('parent_id',"3")                    
    ->setOrder("level")
    ->load();
  if ($categories->count()) {
    $_category = $categories->getLastItem();

    $cur_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
    ?>
    <h3 class="line">Weitere Weine dieses Weinguts</h3>
    <ul class="products-grid home">
      <?php
      $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addCategoryFilter($_category)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image')->setPageSize(4);
      $i = 0;
      foreach ($products as $productModel) {
        $i++;
        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productModel->getId());

        ?>
        <li class="item <?php if ($i == 4): ?>last<?php endif; ?>">

          <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"
             title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>"
             class="product-image"><img
              src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(192); ?>"
              width="192" height="192"
              alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>"/>

            <div class="hover">
              <span><?php echo $this->__('show product') ?></span>
            </div>
          </a>

          <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"
                                      title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>">
              <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></h2>



          <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, false) ?>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <?php echo nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()) ?>
          <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"
             title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>">
            <small><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></small>
          </a>
        </li>
      <?php
      } ?>
    </ul>
  <?php
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "getChildHtml is not working. "?  Can you explain what you tried and didn't work?

Comment: post your view.phtml

Comment: for example $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') is returning nothing. The same template is used for normal product display and it works.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy problem, because the product detail page is quite complex. You either copy everything from the layout.xml and make sure it works in your cms page, or maybe you just use the product detail page for your landingpage?

The third alternative I see is, to implement your own handle either with your own controller or an observer so you can only make all the blocks where they belong.